# C# Winform Textbox Numeric Value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, textbox, double

In my SQL database, I have a table

```
(Product)
(
  Item nvarchar(50),
  Price real
)
```

in my C# winform application, I have a class object of this table

```
class Product
{
  string Item;
  double Price;
}

using binding source, I bind the text property of textbox1.text to Product.Item 
and 
textbox2.text to Product.Price. 

data in my table in the database is as follows, 
Item = Item1
Price = 90.53
```

when the same data is represented in my app and bound to my two textboxes,
textbox1.text = Item1 (no issue here)
but textbox2.text = 90.529998779296875 instead of 90.53.

I can't figure out what makes 90.53 in the database represented as 90.529998779296875 on my textbox?

Comment: Why are you using an approximate data type ([real], [float(24)]) to represent currency (Money [money], [smallmoney])? Use decimal.

Comment: Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. The ISO synonym for real is float(24).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

using money data type in SQL side solved the issue and now i always get the exact number as saved in the database